# UITableView header acting weird iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8

I add a subview as a table header in IB that looks like this:

[image]

However when the app runs it pushes it to the bottom of the table like this:

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: What are your constraints?

Comment: It's an older project, pre autolayout so no constraints.

Comment: Please check the header view's height